# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Utilizando JSON

Tags: php, json, foreach

Estou tentando percorrer o foreach com um array populado em JSON.
Para facilitar estou testando via $_GET (mas já testei com array populado pelo próprio php mas não deu certo).
O $_GET está assim:

```
$amigos = json_decode($_GET['amigos']);
```

O foreach está assim:

```
foreach ($amigos as $a)
```

E os dados passados via $_GET está assim:

```
[{'nome':'bruno','email':'bruno@teste.com'}]
```

Sempre me retorna a mensagem de erro:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Não entendo o porque de acontecer isso.. Alguma ideia?

att

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É um problema com as pelicas, troque para aspas:

```
<?php
$amigos = json_decode('[{"nome":"bruno","email":"bruno@teste.com"}]');
foreach($amigos as $a) {
    echo $a->nome; // bruno
}
```

Comment: fazendo desse modo e apenas retirando a aspas simples antes e depois do array funciona via $_GET, vou testar utilizando o php para gerar o array e retorno aqui..

Comment: Funcionou @AngularMan?

Comment: Funcionou sim @Miguel, obrigado pela ajuda..

Comment: De nada @AngularMan, se a resposta ajudou por favor aceite-a